# Why is this importerror happening?

Tags: python, pycharm

I've got the following project structure:[image]

When I run `main.py` from my IDE everything seems to work fine.

When I try and run `main.py` from the terminal I get the following error: 
[image]

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening.

I thought that since I'm running it from the `SmartHome1` directory then the import of `from SpeechRecognition.TextToSpeech ...` should work (since the import is correct relative to the project root). Why then am I getting this error?

At first I thought the weather.py might "think" that the cwd is different than the project root. So I checked it using os.getcwd() and it showed that it is the root. I'm stumped.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Edit: Now when I think about it, it probably has to do with the fact that `weather.py` is run as a standalone script using `subprocess.Popen`. I'm still not sure how to fix this though.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py answer your question?

Comment: I'm checking it right now.
I've also updated my question a bit at the bottom. I'm pretty sure that me calling `weather.py` using `subprocess.Popen` as a new python instance is the problem.

Comment: `Popen` uses a global python binary and it does see your packages in either Virtualenv or (without Virtualenv) in your project as it's not registered in `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: does SpeachRecognition.__init__.py import TextToSpeach?

Comment: @tdelaney - no it does not. Should it?

Comment: @ThiefMaster - ihm's solution seemed to work. From what I understand that just adds to the pythonpath the `../../` path. This seems more like a workaround than a proper way to do it though.

Comment: I meant the `python -m ....` solution from the accepted answer instead of the sys.path hack.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - I tried running `python -m main` but I got the same result. 
edit: without the `.py`

Comment: @Shookie - I *thought* it had to but after a quick test, turns out you shouldn't need to import it (which I find strange... but thats just me).